# How to run an application only in the background, without opening application window at startup (or auto close it)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have the problem with Windows application that doesn't want to launch only in the background at startup.

I have tried everything from this topic on forum: [How to run an .exe application as a background task on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1168587/how-to-run-an-exe-application-as-a-background-task-on-startup)

I wonder if someone got some fresh idea or maybe is there possibility to automatically close application frame after it's started so it doesn't kill the process but it only closes the window as i would do if i press the X button on top of the app frame.

EDIT: the application that cause me a problem is the messenger downloaded from messenger.com, not from the Microsoft store

Comment: **Windows application**? Which application is it? The proper way to do it would be if the application has a way to launch it silently.

Comment: Yes, I concur with @YisroelTech . If we knew MORE about the application and your use of it, we could make better suggestions.

Comment: It's messenger application, the one downloaded from messenger.com website not from Microsoft store and unfortunately it doesn't have official option to launch silently.